# Adding properties to user model in strongloop

Tags: angularjs, node.js, strongloop

I am using strongloop and the user model can't be found in the composer. How do I add properties into the User model? I have the property sendSMS that I want to add inside the User model. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend User by creating a custom model with User as the base model, then you can fully customize.